# Error "Load Report Failed" before a few reports generated asp.net crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I?m using crystal reports  in a asp application, when I install in a server (IIS) before a few time using the application an generating reports start to show that message,

here is how I call all the reports

```
reporte = ReportFactory.GetReport(reporte.GetType());
reporte.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Rpt/rptVtaTelefonicaAdmin.rpt"));
```

http://s1043.photobucket.com/user/jmperez97/media/2016-11-23_09h38_55_zpsrlahvrqs.png.html?filters[user]=145882609&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=1

Any idea why this appear?

Ps: I'm using .net 3.5
    crystaldecitions.Cristalreports.engine V 2.0.50727

Comment: What message, Can you show this message?

Comment: is just an alert with that message "Load report failed" or a stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "load report failed" error message can be caused by several factors:

1. crystal report is not properly configured on your machine
2. crystal report assemblies installed on your machine do not reflect the assemblies you have on your web.config
3. crystal version installed on the server is different with the one you want to invoke from your site
4. application pool where your reports run is not set to LOCAL SERVICE
5. read and write permission is not enabled on your root folder
6. crystalreportviewer folder is not copied to your operating folder.

[Source](https://forums.asp.net/t/1702597.aspx?Crystal%20report%20error%20Load%20report%20failed%20in%20asp%20net)

Comment: ok, but if is any of this problems why works some time and after this(a few reports 15 or 20) the error appear

Comment: Could be something with the printJobLimit?